# How to start/call a component only when it is in view

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js

This is the code i am trying but it renders as soon as the page is loaded.
I tried hiding it but the animation plays in the background.
Please let me know if there are any fixes
This is the code i am trying but it renders as soon as the page is loaded.
I tried hiding it but the animation plays in the background.
Please let me know if there are any fixes

````
import Terminal from "@nitric/react-animated-term";
import useIsVisible from "./hooks/vos";


const Term = () => {
    const elementRef = useRef();
    const isVisible = useIsVisible(elementRef);
  return (
    <div ref={elementRef} className="bg-[#222222] rounded-b-lg w-2/3 mx-auto text-green-600 mt-24 ter_font">
      <div className="bg-[#333237] py-2 rounded-t-lg flex mb-4">
        <div className="  flex items-center">
          <span className="bg-[#cc0000] px-[6px] py-[6px] rounded-full ml-4 absolute"></span>
          <span className="bg-[#c4a000] px-[6px] py-[6px] rounded-full ml-10 absolute"></span>
          <span className="bg-[#4e9a06] px-[6px] py-[6px] rounded-full ml-16 absolute"></span>
        </div>
        <div className="mx-auto">
          <span className=" text-white font-medium">Hello.js</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="ml-4  ">
        <Terminal lines={termLines} interval={20} replay={false} height={430}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Term;```

 

The component renders as soon as the page is loaded
````

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide or show you have to do **conditional rendering** in **REACT**. I do not know much about Next. Conditional rendering is used when you want to render data based on particular condition.

You have to maintain the state and based on that state change you can render that component. I think it will solve your problem.

Helper Link: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html